# Complex list and len computation

Tags: python

The following code has a output of `[1, 3, 6, 10]`. I understand how to get 1 and 3 but not 6 and 10. 
In 1st loop, the first list item 1 is equal to`[my_list[0]]`, 3 equals to `[out_list[len(out_list)-1] + my_list[i]]`
In 2nd loop, `out_list = 4 + [1 + 3] = 8`which is not 6...

```
def mystery(my_list): 
    out_list = [my_list[0]] 
    for i in range(1, len(my_list)): 
        out_list += [out_list[len(out_list)-1] + my_list[i]] 
    print(out_list)

mystery([1, 2, 3, 4]) #output[1, 3, 6, 10]
```

I'm very close to understand it, just need a bit more explanation. Am I right? 1st loop, out_list = 1, [out_list[len(out_list)-1] = 1, my_list[i]] = 2, therefore, [1, 3]. 2nd loop, out_list stays the same, then I'm stuck here...

Comment: for 3rd loop, when you say 4+[1+3] where are you getting 4,1,3 from?

Comment: 1 = 1, 3 = 1 + 2, 6 = 3 + 3, 10 = 6 + 4.  
actually `out_list[i] = out_list[i-1] + my_list[i]`, every element in `out_list` is the sum of its previous element in `out_list` and `my_list[i]`.

Comment: 1st loop: out_list(=4) = out_list(=1) + [out_list[len(out_list)-1](=1) + my_list[i]](=2)

Comment: In the 1st loop, it is 1(out_list)+(1+2)=4. in the 2nd loop, 4+[1+3]=8, and so on?

Answer (score 0):

1. `out_list[len(out_list)-1]` is simply the last item in out_list, same as `out_list[-1]`.
2. Adding items to the list is done obscurely. Doing `lst += [smtn]` is the same as doing `lst.append(smtn)`

Would this make the function more readable to you?

```
def mystery(my_list): 
    out_list = [my_list[0]] 
    for i in range(1, len(my_list)): 
        out_list.append(out_list[-1] + my_list[i])
    print(out_list)
```

This code returns a list whose i's item is the sum of the first i items of the input. In the i iteration you take the sum of i-1 items (which is stored in i-1), and add the i-th item from the list. 3=1+2, 6=(1+2)+3, 10=(1+2+3)+4. Had the next item in my_list be 5, the next item in out_list would be 10+5 = 15.

Edit:
To clarify more, let's do it by stages.

- `my_list = [1,2,3,4]` and we enter the method
- upon entry, we have `out_list = [my_list[0]]`. so now `out_list = [1]`.
- Now we go into the loop:

  - First iteration, i=1. `out_list[len(out_list)-1] + my_list[i]` = `out_list[0] + my_list[1]` = `1 + 2` = `3`. `out_list = [1,3]`
  - Second iteration, i=2. `out_list[len(out_list)-1] + my_list[i]` = `out_list[1] + my_list[2]` = `3 + 3` = `6.` `out_list = [1,3,6]`
  - Third iteration, i=3. `out_list[len(out_list)-1] + my_list[i]` = `out_list[2] + my_list[3]` = `6 + 4` = `10.` `out_list = [1,3,6,10]`

Comment: In the 1st loop, it is 1(out_list)+(1+2)=4. in the 2nd loop, 4+[1+3]=8, and so on?

Comment: 1st loop, [1]+[3]. 2nd loop, [1]+[3]+[[out_list[len(out_list)-1] + 3], is that [[out_list[len(out_list)-1] = 3?

Comment: @dfefef I've added a step by step clarification to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
output = mystery([1, 2, 3, 4]) # [1, 3, 6, 10]
output == [1, 1+2, 1+2+3, 1+2+3+4]
```

Comment: In the 1st loop, it is 1(out_list)+(1+2)=4. in the 2nd loop, 4+[1+3]=8, and so on?

Comment: adding 2 lists together doesn't sum them. It concatenates them. So the code is actually turning the number into a list. It looks like `[1]+[3]` which turns into `[1,3]`. Then `[1,3]+[6]` which is `[1,3,6]`

Comment: 1st loop, [1]+[3]. 2nd loop, [1]+[3]+[[out_list[len(out_list)-1] + 3], is that [[out_list[len(out_list)-1] = 3?

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Comment: I'm very close to understand it, just need a bit more explanation. Am I right? 1st loop, out_list = 1, [out_list[len(out_list)-1] = 1, my_list[i]] = 2, therefore, [1, 3]. 2nd loop, out_list stays the same, then I'm stuck here...

Comment: It's just the sum of all previous elements man. Each loop, out_list `+=` means set out_list to be whatever it was before, plus this other list that comes after. So `outlist[len(out_list)-1]` is the last element, that plus `my_list[i]` is appended to outlist, and on the next loop is returned by `outlist[len(out_list)-1]`

Answer (score 0):

my_list initially is :  [1, 2, 3, 4]
   out_list initially is :  [1]

out_list in 1 iteration  outlist on each iter : [1]
   here i is : 1
   len(out_list) :  1  my_list[i]:  2
   add next element using this statement : out_list += [out_list[len(out_list)-1] +    my_list[i]] 
   check here : out_list[0] gives 1 add this to 2

out_list in 2 iteration  outlist on each iter : [1, 3]
   here i is : 2
   len(out_list) :  2  my_list[i]:  3
   add next element using this statement : out_list += [out_list[len(out_list)-1] +   my_list[i]] 
   check here : out_list[1] gives 3 add this to 3

out_list in 3 iteration  outlist on each iter : [1, 3, 6]
   here i is : 3
   len(out_list) :  3  my_list[i]:  4
   add next element using this statement : out_list += [out_list[len(out_list)-1] + my_list[i]] 
   check here : out_list[2] gives 6 add this to 4

Finally output is : [1, 3, 6, 10]

out_list += [out_list[len(out_list)-1] + my_list[i]]  this statement it appends previous element into out_list i.e why out_list += is used instead out_list = so only in 3rd and 4th iteration the result is 6 and 10

Comment: @dfefef : the above procedure will give you idea how you are getting 6 in 3rd iteration and 10 in 4th iteration.... because out_list is list for which elements are adding in each iteration.

Answer (score -1):

A pythonic way to do this really easily:

```
def summer_foo(my_list):
    return [sum(my_list[:i+1]) for i in range(len(my_list))]
```

**Brief explanation**

1. Loop from 0 to the len of the list - `len(my_list)`
2. Sum all the elements which goes from 0 to `i`
3. Put this element in the list (this is done with the comprehension)

if `i`is equal to 0 you will get the first element.

if `i`is equal to 1 you will get the sum of the first and the second element (`i` belongs to [0,2))

And so on...

Comment: In the 1st loop, it is 1(out_list)+(1+2)=4. in the 2nd loop, 4+[1+3]=8, and so on?

Comment: note this is n^2 instead of the original's linear time, because we are recomputing sums for each element, instead of reusing the sum of all previous elements.